# Link ISR to vector interrupt 80x86 32bit AT&T assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I work on Intel-Atom 32bits (Assembly AT&T).

I want to link my ISR to a vector interrupt 0x33:

```
push %ebp   //save the context to swith back
movl %esp,%ebp

movl $OSTickISR, %eax //address of int 0x33 = address of OSTickISR
movl $0x33*4, %ebx
movl %eax, (%ebx)

pop %ebp //Return to the calling function
ret
```

When I try to use my int $0x33, nothing happends !!!

What was wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :), as there is a BIOS, it already built the GDT/IDT, so I found the address of IDT using sidt and sgdt instructions, and i added my ISR to sidt

Answer (score 3):

In x86 32 bit, ISR information is stored in an IDT. The IDT is not simply a list of addresses, and is not necessarily stored at the address 0. For a description of the IDT format, see the [OSDev Wiki page](http://wiki.osdev.org/IDT). The location of the IDT is determined by the OS, and it might not be accessible to user mode software. Assuming you do have the right to modify it, you can get the location of the IDT using the `sidt` instruction.

```
sidt -6(%esp)
```

In 32 bit mode, `sidt` will store 6 bytes worth of data at the specified location. I used `-6(%esp)` for my example, which will store the data just below the current stack. The low two bytes are the length of the IDT, in bytes, and the next 4 (in 32 bit mode) are the address of the IDT. Since each IDT entry is 8 bytes long, the location of the entry you want would be `0x33*8` bytes after the start of the IDT. Before modifying the entry, you should ensure the IDT actually contains that entry (it is at least `0x34*8` bytes long).

Here is an example which finds the IDT, ensures it is long enough, and sets the entry for interrupt 0x33.

```
sidt    -6(%esp)          // Get the location and size of the IDT
cmpw    $0x34*8, -6(%esp) // Make sure the IDT is long enough
jb      IDT_too_short     //  and handle the error if it isn't
mov     -4(%esp), %ebx    // Get the IDT's address
add     $0x33*8, %ebx     //  and move to the entry for 0x33
mov     $OSTickISR, %eax  // Get the ISR's address
mov     %ax, (%ebx)       // Store the low 16 bits of the ISR's address
movw    $ISR_CS, 2(%ebx)  // Store the code segment which should be used with this ISR
movb    $0, 4(%ebx)       // This has to be 0
movb    $0xEE, 5(%ebx)    // See the OSDev link for information on this byte.
                          // 0xEE is most common for interrupts available from user mode
shr     $16, %eax
mov     %ax, 6(%ebx)      // Store the high 16 bits of the ISR's address
```

Comment: +1 Great answer, I have nothing to add except the obligatory link to the [IA Software Developers Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html). (oh and for completeness maybe throw in a `sub $8, %esp` at the top :)

Comment: @user786653 Thanks for the link. As for the `sub $8, %esp`, my response depends on your reasoning. If 1) you were aligning the stack for the function, that isn't necessary since there are no function calls, or 2) you want to work with positive offsets of `%esp`, I prefer to work in the red zone for such small amounts of data whenever possible.

Comment: I wanted to allocate room on the stack, as I don't recall having used a calling convention with a red zone on 32-bit x86? Either way, anyone capable of understanding and using the above code should easily be able to make appropriate adjustments for their calling convention :)

Comment: thank you,

when i test this code, it goes always in IDT_too_short macro !!!, after investigation using this code:

sidt    -6(%esp)
movb    -1(%esp),%ah
movb    -2(%esp),%al
movb    -3(%esp),%bh
movb    -4(%esp),%bl
movb    -5(%esp),%ch
movb    -6(%esp),%cl

%ah = 00
%al = 00
%bh = 03
%bl = 06
%ch = 00
%cl = 00
as I am in 32bit so the interpretation should be : DEST[0:15] ← IDTR(Limit) = 0x00 DEST[16:47] ← IDTR(Base); FI; (* Full 32-bit base address stored *) = 0x00603

I feel like I am lost ?????

Comment: @mustapha You have your `bh` and `bl` in the wrong order, the specified address is `0x306`. But it appears its length is 0, so the location doesn't matter. You can create the IDT yourself by allocating memory and using `lidt`, just make sure you fill unused interrupts with 0.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw : i tried to build an IDT, but it did not work, i am sorry if i ask again, but i am new to this field             Load_IDT:
push    %ebp    //save the context to swith back
mov     %esp,%ebp

movw    $256*8, -6(%esp) //256 ISR possible
movl    $IDT, -4(%esp)   //IDT is a table of 256*8bytes
lidt    -6(%esp)

pop     %ebp //Return to the calling function
ret

Answer (score 1):

An address on x86 consists of a segment and an offset. In real mode, it's segment*16 + offset. In protected mode there's a bit of indirection: the segment register it's really a selector that points to a segment descriptor, which contains the segment base and limit, along with other segment attributes. Instructions that access memory can take an explicit segment specifier (e.g: `DS:BX`), or else they take an implicit segment which depends on the register used (e.g: if you use SP the implicit segment is SS).

The IVT in real mode is at address 0000:0000, the IDT in protected mode is at address IDT:0000, where IDT can be accessed via LIDT/SIDT instructions.

You should also take into consideration that if you are running over a Virtual Memory Operating System, you don't have direct access to physical memory, the addresses in your program are virtual addresses that get translated to physical addresses after segmentation and paging.